# Atmega328 component library for Protel 99 SE

Tags: arduino-uno

Any one know a **component library** for Arduino UNO (**Atmega328**, etc) for **Protel 99 SE** PCB design software?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it here with 94 chips.

The author states, "I have made a little library for Protel 99SE with schematic sybols of AVR chips."

http://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/avr-8bit-microcontrollers-protel-99-library

Answer (score 1):

All arduino design schematics are available from the Arduino website, e.g. for the [Uno](http://arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/arduino_Uno_Rev3-02-TH.zip). However, these are in EAGLE format, I don't know if it's possible to convert.